# C Malloc causing undefined behavior with stdout

Tags: c, debugging, malloc, undefined-behavior

I shaved this down as much as possible while still preserving the error.

`printf()` is not displaying anywhere within the program but will work when I remove certain lines like `errno = EBADMSG;` in `foobar2()`. I'm suspicious that the malloc in `foobar2()` is the source of the undefined behavior but cannot seem to resolve it.

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/uYwrqSrh0)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct foo_t {
    unsigned char *a;
    unsigned char *b;
    unsigned char *c;
    unsigned char *d;
} foo;

void bar1(foo *m);
void bar2(foo *m);

int main() {
    foo m = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
    bar1(&m);
    
    return 0;
}

void bar1(foo *m) {
    bar2(m);
    printf("This is not printing.");
}

void bar2(foo *m) {
    unsigned char *buffer = "Hello World\r\nfoo";
    ssize_t str_size = strlen((const char *)buffer);
    int i, start, end = 0;
    
    if (isalpha(buffer[0]) <= 0) {
        errno = EBADMSG;
    }
    
    // Extract substr to newline.
    int str_len = 13;
    m->a = (unsigned char *)malloc(str_len + 1);
    memset(m->a, '\0', str_len + 1);
    strncpy(m->a, buffer + start, str_len);
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `start` in `bar2`.

Comment: Hint: Invest some 30 minutes or so and learn the basics of your debugger. Then you would have found the problem in a couple of minutes yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Compiling your code with warnings enabled (`clang -Weverything`), I get 9 warnings! Let's fix them in order:

```
220503-crash.c:31:20: warning: initializing 'unsigned char *' with an expression of type 'char [17]' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
    unsigned char *buffer = "Hello World\r\nfoo";
                   ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Indeed why do you insist on `unsigned char`? You should either cast the string literal or use `const char *` which is a much more appropriate type.

```
220503-crash.c:32:24: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'unsigned long' to 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') [-Wsign-conversion]
    ssize_t str_size = strlen((const char *)buffer);
            ~~~~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why use non standard type `ssize_t` (defined in POSIX but not in the C Standard)? `strlen` returns a `size_t`.

```
220503-crash.c:41:44: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
    m->a = (unsigned char *)malloc(str_len + 1);
                            ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Changing the type of `str_len` t `size_t` would fix this one. The cast `(unsigned char *)` is useless in C, albeit it is needed in C++.

```
220503-crash.c:43:13: warning: passing 'unsigned char *' to parameter of type 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
    strncpy(m->a, buffer + start, str_len);
            ^~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:119:28: note: expanded from macro 'strncpy'
  __builtin___strncpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                           ^~~~
```

Indeed `strncpy` takes a `char *`. Beware that `strncpy` is not yor friend: it does not do what most programmers think. In this particular case, you should use `memcpy` and make sure you set the null terminator at `m->a[str_len]`... Which you have already via `memset()`, but why not use `calloc()` if you want the memory block to be zero initialized?

```
220503-crash.c:43:19: warning: passing 'unsigned char *' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
    strncpy(m->a, buffer + start, str_len);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:119:34: note: expanded from macro 'strncpy'
  __builtin___strncpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                 ^~~
```

Same remark as above: Use the correct type for `buffer` too.

```
220503-crash.c:33:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
    int i, start, end = 0;
        ^
220503-crash.c:33:19: warning: unused variable 'end' [-Wunused-variable]
    int i, start, end = 0;
                  ^
220503-crash.c:32:13: warning: unused variable 'str_size' [-Wunused-variable]
    ssize_t str_size = strlen((const char *)buffer);
            ^
```

Get rid of unused variables (but you have an excuse as you shaved the program down to a minimal compilable example, so no offense).

```
220503-crash.c:43:28: warning: variable 'start' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    strncpy(m->a, buffer + start, str_len);
                           ^~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:119:34: note: expanded from macro 'strncpy'
  __builtin___strncpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                 ^~~
220503-crash.c:33:17: note: initialize the variable 'start' to silence this warning
    int i, start, end = 0;
                ^
                 = 0
```

This is a major offender! You have undefined behavior, and the program may crash because you read from an invalid address, thus preventing the message from appearing.  I don't know if you set variable `start` somewhere else in the original program... if not, you know what to do.

Here are some more remarks:

- the only thing specified for the return value of function `isalpha()` and other `isxxx` from `<ctype.h>` is *The functions in this subclause return nonzero (true) if and only if the value of the argument `c` conforms to that in the description of the function.*

Hence it makes no sense to write:

```
  if (isalpha(buffer[0]) <= 0) {
      errno = EBADMSG;
  }
```

- allocating memory with `malloc()` then initializing it with `memset()` is error prone. Better use `calloc()` for this. In your case, this initialization is optional as long as you set the null terminator after copying the string contents, or if you use `strcpy()` for this. `strndup()` could be used to allocate the copy in a simpler and safer way. This function is available on POSIX systems.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct foo_t {
    const char *a;
    const char *b;
    const char *c;
    const char *d;
} foo;

void bar1(foo *m);
void bar2(foo *m);

int main() {
    foo m = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
    bar1(&m);
    return 0;
}

void bar1(foo *m) {
    bar2(m);
    printf("This is printing.\n");
}

void bar2(foo *m) {
    const char *buffer = "Hello World\r\nfoo";

    if (!isalpha((unsigned char)buffer[0])) {
        errno = EBADMSG;
    }

    // Extract substr to newline.
    size_t start = 0;
    while (buffer[start] && !isalpha((unsigned char)buffer[start])) {
        start++;
    }
    size_t len = 0;
    while (buffer[start + len]) {
        if (buffer[start + len++] == '\n')
            break;
    }
    m->a = strndup(buffer + start, len);
}
```